# How can I calculate a sample path for a simple stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I try to find a trajectory (sample path) for such very simple Gaussian stochastic process: $X(\omega;t)=N(\mu t,\sigma^2)$, $t\in T=(-\infty, \infty)$ ($N$, as always, is the Gaussian distribution). As for any $t$ the process is a Gaussian random variable, it is easy to find expectation, variance, finite-dimensional probability distributions of $X$.
However, it is not very easy to find a trajectory. I suppose, that it has the form: $\mu t+b$, where $b$ is a real number, but it is desirable to prove this

Comment: There are many gaussian processes.  The structure of the trajectories depends on the covariance between $X_t$ and $X_s$.

Comment: Take 2 independent Brownian motions both starting at 0 at time 0 , you then reindex the first one so that time flows from $0$ to $-\infty$ and sew it with the second one at $t=0$ with its natural indexation.  If you multiply this process by $\sigma/\sqrt(|t|)$ and add to it the trend $\mu.t$ you have something unless mistaken is what you are looking for (of course the necessary condition mentioned by user6247850 is that increments between $s<t$ from $u<v$ with $t<u$ are indep. and have Gaussian law $N(\mu.(t-s), \sigma^2)$ unless mistaken), to which you add that its value is 0 at time 0..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Define $$X_t = \mu t + X$$
Then $X_t$ has the properties you desire.

Comment: Exactly! And very easy!

Comment: @Konstantin if this answer has solved your problem, please do upvote+accept if you want :)